# Old answers don't work - XeLaTex fontspec crash on Texmaker [LaTeX error: “kernel/invalid-variant”]

Tags: fontspec, latex-base

I'm reviving an old issue which I have come across. There are many similar questions but dated from a few years.

Basically using Miktek 2.9.7100 with everything up to date and Texmaker 5.0.3. I can't compile the package `fontspec` with `XeLaTeX`. Using the Quick Build `XeLaTeX + View PDF`

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Hello world! 
\end{document}
```

error:

```
! LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant"!! Variant form 'e' invalid for base form '\tl_if_empty_p:n'.!! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.!! For immediate help type H <return>.!............................................... \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty_p:n {e}
```

The most populare answer was to install `l3kernel`. I have the package from 10/09/2019 installed. But it still does not work.

Comment: The formatting of the error message suggests that your version of `l3kernel` is rather old. Could you `\listfiles` before the `\documentclass`, compile your document, and show the log file, please?

Comment: Run miktex updates as user **and** as admin. You quite certainly have an old version somewhere.

Comment: Updating with **user privileges** did the trick! I'll let you answer if you want the reputation points. Miktek is really a strange piece of software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolving the issue was simply running the update both in user **and** admin modes. The answer was given by @ulrike-fischer